# Getting to the last page in a website when the 'go to last page' button doesn't work

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I need to get to the last page in the following site [link](https://mahabocw.in/essential-kit-benefits-distribution/). This is because when I right click on a row I would be able to export all previous rows along with it as a csv file. That way, I can download the complete data present in the website.

But the problem is that the `Go to last page` option doesn't work. So I am currently using selenium to click through the next page button to eventually reach the last page. But it takes a lot of time.

This is the code I am currently using.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://mahabocw.in/essential-kit-benefits-distribution/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

for i in range(1000000):
    next_button = '/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/article/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]/div[3]/button'
    click_next = driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button)
    click_next.click()
```

Is there any way I could modify the code in the website and maybe make the particular button : `Go to last page` to work so I can go to that page and download all the data. Or is there some better technique I could adopt using Selenium.

Any help or suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Check the Network tab in the devtools. For each page change, there is new request. I would try scraping the data using purely API.

Comment: I am quite new to sending requests in the API. I'll check it out. Do tell me if you know of methods to send requests

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but it seems that there are at least three libraries: requests, httplib, urllib. Check what suits you.